# Mapping ICollection to Object with Automapper

Tags: c#, unit-testing, automapper, asp.net-core-webapi, nunit-3.0

I am trying to map an ICollection of News to a BreakingNewsDto:

```
    public class Division
    {
        public Division()
        {
            Newses = new HashSet<News>();
            Articles = new HashSet<Article>();
            Contacts = new HashSet<Contact>();
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<News> Newses { get; }

        public virtual ICollection<Article> Articles { get; }

        public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; }

        public Guid PhotoId { get; set; }

        public virtual Photo Image { get; set; }

        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    }

    public class BreakingNewsDto
    {

        public BreakingNewsDto()
        {
            News = new List<NewsDto>();
        }
        public int TotalAmount { get; set; }

        public ICollection<NewsDto> News { get; set; }
    }    

public class NewsDto
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public string HeadLine { get; set; }

        public string Slug { get; set; }

        public string Article { get; set; }

        public string Author { get; set; }
    }
```

All in all that worked quite fine until I tried to add the BreakingNewsDto to map the Collection of News to the Dto. I Used the following Mappings and Converters:

```
CreateMap<ICollection<News>, BreakingNewsDto>().ConvertUsing<NewsToBreakingNewsConverter>();

CreateMap<Division, FullDivisionDto>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.News, a => a.MapFrom(src => src.Newses))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.UserId, a => a.Ignore());

public class NewsToBreakingNewsConverter : ITypeConverter<ICollection<News>, BreakingNewsDto>
{
    public BreakingNewsDto Convert(ICollection<News> source, BreakingNewsDto destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        destination.TotalAmount = source.Count;
        foreach (var news in source)
        {
           destination.News.Add(Mapper.Map<News, NewsDto>(news));
        }

        return destination;
    }
}
```

When I try to use that I get the following Error:

```
> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types.
> 
> Mapping types: Division -> FullDivisionDto
> TsvMeine.Domain.Entities.Division ->
> TsvMeine.Application.Ressources.Division.FullDivisionDto
> 
> Type Map configuration: Division -> FullDivisionDto
> TsvMeine.Domain.Entities.Division ->
> TsvMeine.Application.Ressources.Division.FullDivisionDto
> 
> Destination Member: News  ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object
> reference not set to an instance of an object.    at
> TsvMeine.Application.MappingProfiles.Converters.NewsToBreakingNewsConverter.Convert(ICollection`1
> source, BreakingNewsDto destination, ResolutionContext context) in
> D:\Users\Jonas\VisualStudios\Enterprise\Website\Code\Core\Application\TsvMeine.Application\MappingProfiles\Converters\NewsToBreakingNewsConverter.cs:line
> 12    at lambda_method(Closure , Division , FullDivisionDto ,
> ResolutionContext )    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---   
> at lambda_method(Closure , Division , FullDivisionDto ,
> ResolutionContext )    at
> AutoMapper.Mapper.AutoMapper.IMapper.Map[TSource,TDestination](TSource
> source) in C:\projects\automapper\src\AutoMapper\Mapper.cs:line 233   
> at
> TsvMeine.Persistence.Services.DivisionService.GetDivisionAsync(Int32
> divisionId, Boolean overrideIsActive, CancellationToken token) in
> D:\Users\Jonas\VisualStudios\Enterprise\Website\Code\Infrastructure\Persistence\TsvMeine.Persistence\Services\DivisionService.cs:line
> 130
```

From the Stacktrace so far I can see that destination in my Converter is a Nullpointer. So I fixed that with adding this:

```
public BreakingNewsDto Convert(ICollection<News> source, BreakingNewsDto destination, ResolutionContext context)
        {
            destination = new BreakingNewsDto();
            destination.TotalAmount = source.Count;
            foreach (var news in source)
            {
               destination.News.Add(Mapper.Map<News, NewsDto>(news));
            }

            return destination;
        }
```

However I am still getting an error:

> ```
> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types.
>
> Mapping types:
> Division -> FullDivisionDto
> TsvMeine.Domain.Entities.Division -> TsvMeine.Application.Ressources.Division.FullDivisionDto
>
> Type Map configuration:
> Division -> FullDivisionDto
> TsvMeine.Domain.Entities.Division -> TsvMeine.Application.Ressources.Division.FullDivisionDto
> ```
>
> Destination Member:
>       News
>        ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Mapper not initialized. Call Initialize with appropriate configuration. If you are trying to use mapper instances through a container or otherwise, make sure you do not have any calls to the static Mapper.Map methods, and if you're using ProjectTo or UseAsDataSource extension methods, make sure you pass in the appropriate IConfigurationProvider instance.
>          at AutoMapper.Mapper.get_Instance() in C:\projects\automapper\src\AutoMapper\Mapper.cs:line 36
>          at AutoMapper.Mapper.Map[TSource,TDestination](TSource source) in C:\projects\automapper\src\AutoMapper\Mapper.cs:line 96
>          at TsvMeine.Application.MappingProfiles.Converters.NewsToBreakingNewsConverter.Convert(ICollection`1 source, BreakingNewsDto destination, ResolutionContext context) in D:\Users\Jonas\VisualStudios\Enterprise\Website\Code\Core\Application\TsvMeine.Application\MappingProfiles\Converters\NewsToBreakingNewsConverter.cs:line 16
>          at lambda_method(Closure , Division , FullDivisionDto , ResolutionContext )
>          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>          at lambda_method(Closure , Division , FullDivisionDto , ResolutionContext )
>          at AutoMapper.Mapper.AutoMapper.IMapper.Map[TSource,TDestination](TSource source) in C:\projects\automapper\src\AutoMapper\Mapper.cs:line 233
>          at TsvMeine.Persistence.Services.DivisionService.GetDivisionAsync(Int32 divisionId, Boolean overrideIsActive, CancellationToken token) in D:\Users\Jonas\VisualStudios\Enterprise\Website\Code\Infrastructure\Persistence\TsvMeine.Persistence\Services\DivisionService.cs:line 130

Now I have two questions:

1. What do I need to do to get a initialized Destination in my Converter instead of creating my own?
2. How do I initialize my Mapper correctly to use it in an Asp.Net Core Web API?

### Edit

Sorry It seems I forgot the most relevant part. Obviously it is correct to use (and I am already using it) the Automapper DI Package mentioned in the comments. However right now I am trying to do Unit/Integration Testing of my Services and stuff like this and there I do not have my DI Container. However I still want to use the "real" Automapper and not a Fake Implementation to see if my Mappings are correct or not. Therefore I tried to set up Automapper like this:

```
    config = new MapperConfiguration(x =>
    {
        x.AddProfile<DomainToDtoMappingProfile>();
        x.AddProfile<DtoToDomainMappingProfile>();

    });
    _mapper = config.CreateMapper();
```

However this seems to be not enough to make the Conversion work.
So my two questions still remain.

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection). You only get a destination if you pass one to Map. You should probably rewrite your mappings so you don't map the collection by hand.

Comment: Thank you for Commenting and pointing me to the things that I forgot to mention. @LucianBargaoanu Would you please look at my edited question and see if you have a good Answer.

Comment: @Brezelmann Your code is using the static API while in the last snippet you configure the instance API.

Comment: @Nkosi Ah. Does that mean that I need to inject the IMapper into my ValueConverter by Constructor Injection or how should I get a correct Instance?